# \markboth can't tell right and left?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

```
https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/88/88-S2.tex
```

Here is an example file. I am looking at the use of `\markboth`.
Unless I am mistaken, and there is another defition linked with headings, `\markboth{left head}{right head}` should mean exactly what it means.

However the compiled file with `\markboth{}{Paper II, 1988}`, only inputs `Paper II, 1988` on the LEFT HANDSIDE. I should expect it to be on the RIGHT...

I tried with `\pagestyle{myheadings}` and `\pagestyle{headings}`, neither works. And there is no way to clear the left hand side header (i.e. the page numbers).

What's the problem here??

Lots and lots of files have the same properties (problem)

```
https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/88/88-S2.tex
https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/89/89-S1.tex
https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/db/95/95-S3.tex
```

**UPDATE**

Mystery solved with `twoside`, but my question is now, why wouldn't the normal single side work??? Why can't it tell left and right?

In the [help here](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-264.html), it does not really say we have to use `twoside`...so assuming it should work too.

How do I change/delete the page number for example? It seems there is no way to access the right header ...

Comment: `oneside` by definition has no left- or right-hand side.  The "side" refers to the facing pages on a two-page spread, not to the left- or right-hand side of a single running head, which is what it seems you are asking for.  (I haven't looked at the linked files; it's expected here that example code will be included in the question, since links can go dead, and this resource is intended to continue to be useful into the future.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\markboth` stores its arguments in the left and right side of a mark. It doesn't decide where (and if at all) this is then used. That is the job of the page style. Typically in a twoside document page styles use `\leftmark` (the left part of the last mark on the page) on even/left pages and `\rightmark` (the right part of the first mark) on right pages. In oneside documents typically only the right part is used. But this can be changed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{leftmark: \leftmark, right mark: \rightmark}
\begin{document}
some text

\markboth{LEFT1}{RIGHT1}
\markboth{LEFT2}{RIGHT2}
\end{document}
```

[image]